# Python pipeline using GNU Parallel

Tags: python, pipe, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to write a wrapper around GNU Parallel in Python to run a command in parallel, but seem to be misunderstanding either how GNU Parallel works, system pipes and/or python subprocess pipes.

Essentially I am looking to use GNU Parallel to handle splitting up an input file and then running another command in parallel on multiple hosts.

I can investigate some pure python way to do this in the future, but it seems like it should be easily implemented using GNU Parallel.

**t.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

print
print sys.stdin.read()
print
```

**p.py**

```
from subprocess import *
import os
from os.path import *

args = ['--block', '10', '--recstart', '">"', '--sshlogin', '3/:', '--pipe', './t.py']

infile = 'test.fa'

fh = open('test.fa','w')
fh.write('''>M02261:11:000000000-ADWJ7:1:1101:16207:1115 1:N:0:1
CAGCTACTCGGGGAATCCTTGTTGCTGAGCTCTTCCCTTTTCGCTCGCAGCTACTCGGGGAATCCTTGTTGCTGAGCTCTTCCCTTTTCGCTCGCAGCTACTCGGGGAATCCTTGTTGCTGAGCTCTTCCCTTTTCGCTCGCAGCTACTCGGGGAATCCTTGTTGCTGAGCTCTTCCCTTT
>M02261:11:000000000-ADWJ7:1:1101:21410:1136 1:N:0:1
ATAGTAGATAGGGACATAGGGAATCTCGTTAATCCATTCATGCGCGTCACTAATTAGATGACGAGGCATTTGGCTACCTTAAGAGAGTCATAGTTACTCCCGCCGTTTACC
>M02261:11:000000000-ADWJ7:1:1101:13828:1155 1:N:0:1
GGTTTAGAGTCTCTAGTCGATAGATCAATGTAGGTAAGGGAAGTCGGCAAATTAGATCCGTAACTTCGGGATAAGGATTGGCTCTGAAGGCTGGGATGACTCGGGCTCTGGTGCCTTCGCGGGTGCTTTGCCTCAACGCGCGCCGGCCGGCTCGGGTGGTTTGCGCCGCCTGTGGTCGCGTCGGCCGCTGCAGTCATCAATAAACAGCCAATTCAGAACTGGCACGGCTGAGGGAATCCGACGGTCTAATTAAAACAAAGCATTGTGATGGACTCCGCAGGTGTTGACACAATGTGATTTT
>M02261:11:000000000-ADWJ7:1:1101:14120:1159 1:N:0:1
GAGTAGCTGCGAGCGAAAAGGGAAGAGCTCAAGGGGAGGAAAAGAAACTAACAAGGATTCCCCGAGTAGCTGCGAGCGAAAAGGGAAGCGCCCAAGGGGGGCAACAGGAACTAACAAGAATTCGCCGACTAGCTGCGACCTGAAAAGGAAAAACCCAAGGGGAGGAAAAGAAACTAACAAGGATTCCCCGAGTAGCTGCGAGCAGAAAAGGAAAAGCACAAGAGGAGGAAACGACACTAATAAGACTTCCCATACAAGCGGCGAGCAAAACAGCACGAGCCCAACGGCGAGAAAAGCAAAA
>M02261:11:000000000-ADWJ7:1:1101:8638:1172 1:N:0:1
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
''')
fh.close()

# Call 1
Popen(['parallel']+args, stdin=open(infile,'rb',0), stdout=open('output','w')).wait()

# Call 2
_cat = Popen(['cat', infile], stdout=PIPE)
Popen(['parallel']+args, stdin=_cat.stdout, stdout=open('output2','w')).wait()

# Call 3
Popen('cat '+infile+' | parallel ' + ' '.join(args), shell=True, stdout=open('output3','w')).wait()
```

Call 1 and Call 2 produce the same output while Call 3 produces the output I would expect where the input file was split up and contains empty lines between records.

I'm more curious about what the differences are between Call 1,2 and Call 3.

Comment: Are you open to using something other than GNU parallel? If you're already working in python [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) may be an easier way to push your data around. Other approaches including using [IPython.parallel](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/) with the SSH cluster management, or [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) a distributed task queue

Comment: The script will be eventually be running inside of a PBS or SGE job so fabric would probably work best. For now, I'm just interested in what the differences are in the calls.

Comment: Definitely have a look at IPython which already includes code for both PBS and SGE

Comment: The latter two both appear to suffer from a [Useless Use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html). The third additionally assembles the commands into a string to be parsed back into arguments by the shell, which is also similarly useless when you already have the arguments separated.

Comment: I was unaware that you could actually supply the args list as a list when doing an actual shell pipeline. I was pretty sure when you were running the pipeline in the actual shell(aka shell=True) you had to supply an argument string not a list.

Comment: When  you *don't* invoke a shell, you mustn't double-quote the `--recstart` option  argument (or generally use any quotes at all where their purpose was to bypass some mechansm of the shell).

Comment: It was for sure that I had quoted the argument. I don't think it is necessary to mention the Useless use of cat in an example though where the question was centered around understanding if there was a difference between cat | parallel and supplying stdin=open(file)

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your question what parameters you are investigating.  The [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) documentation recommends, but does not require, the command to be a single string when `shell=True` (though to pass a list, on Unix, you'd still have to make the entire command line a single string; it gets passed to `/bin/sh`, `-c`, *args*).

Comment: On a side note: `--block 10` will take blocks of 10 bytes. That is probably not what you want. Maybe `-N10` is what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TL;DR* Don't quote `">"` when `shell=False`.

If you use `shell=True`, you can use all the shell's facilities, like globbing, I/O redirection, etc.  You will need to quote anything which needs to be escaped from the shell.  You can pass the entire command line as a single string, and the shell will parse it.

```
unsafe = subprocess.Popen('echo `date` "my files" * >output', shell=True)
```

With `shell=False`, you have no "secret" side effects behind the scenes, and none of the shell's facilities are available to you.  So you need to take care of globbing, redirection, etc on the Python side.  On the plus account, you save a (potentially significant) extra process, you have more control, and you don't need (and indeed mustn't) quote things which had to be quoted when the shell was involved.  In summary, this is also safer, because you can see exactly what you are doing.

```
cmd = ['echo']
cmd.append(datestamp())
cmd.append['my files']  # notice absence of shell quotes around string
cmd.extend(glob('*'))
safer = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=open('output', 'w+'))
```

(This still differs slightly, because with modern shells, `echo` is a builtin, whereas now, we will be executing an external utility `/bin/echo` or whichever executable with that name comes first in your `PATH`.)

Now, returning to your examples, the problem in your `args` is that you are quoting a literal `">"` as the record separator.  When a shell is involved, an unquoted right broket would invoke redirection, so to specify it as a string, it has to be escaped or quoted; but when no shell is in the picture, there isn't anything which handles (or requires) those quotes, so to pass a literal `>` argument, simply pass that literally.

With that out of the way, your call #1 definitely seems like the way to go.  (Though I'm not entirely convinced that it's sane to write a Python wrapper for a shell command implemented in Perl.  I suspect that juggling a bunch of parallel child processes in Python directly would not be more complicated.)